# Running PHPDocumentor

Tags: travis-ci

This command runs fine locally, but not during the build

```
php vendor/bin/phpdoc -d . -t ./build/docs --ignore vendor/,build/,hm-backup/,backdrop/,assets/,bin/,languages/,node_modules/,tests/,readme/
```

Here's the output

```
  $ php vendor/bin/phpdoc -d $TRAVIS_BUILD_DIR -t ./build/docs --ignore vendor/,build/,hm-backup/,backdrop/,assets/,bin/,languages/,node_modules/,tests/,readme/
  Collecting files .. OK
  Initializing parser .. OK
  Parsing files

  [Exception]                                                                  
  No parsable files were found, did you specify any using the -f or -d parameter?
```

[Travis CI build output](https://travis-ci.org/humanmade/backupwordpress/jobs/42514366#L328)

Does the `.` not refer to current working dir? or is it not the repository root?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not assume that `.` is the directory where your repository is checked out.

Travis actually provides a special [environment variable](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/ci-environment/#Environment-variables) that points to your repository: `TRAVIS_BUILD_DIR`

So you could write your line as

```
php vendor/bin/phpdoc -d $TRAVIS_BUILD_DIR -t $TRAVIS_BUILD_DIR/build/docs --ignore $TRAVIS_BUILD_DIR/vendor/,$TRAVIS_BUILD_DIR/build/,$TRAVIS_BUILD_DIR/hm-backup/,$TRAVIS_BUILD_DIR/backdrop/,$TRAVIS_BUILD_DIR/assets/,$TRAVIS_BUILD_DIR/bin/,$TRAVIS_BUILD_DIR/languages/,$TRAVIS_BUILD_DIR/node_modules/,$TRAVIS_BUILD_DIR/tests/,$TRAVIS_BUILD_DIR/readme/
```

Comment: Yes I had tried that before with the var wrapped in quotes, tried without quotes, but no luck either 

https://travis-ci.org/humanmade/backupwordpress/jobs/42629004#L321